# ODBC connection fails over network, but works fine on computers not on the network

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, network-programming, odbc

I have an MS Access backend to which an Excel (2010) front-end should connect and import data to existing tables in the workbook.

I've set up a routine to allow users to specify the location of the Access back end anywhere on their network, and once connected, those tables are meant to  refresh.

Everything works on computers that aren't connected to the network, or when using Excel 2016 on a computer connected to the network.

I've never had a problem like this before with either 2010 or 2016, and I've had the network guys check AV & FW settings, and nothing appears to be blocked.

MS Query fails in the 2010 version when manually trying to connect to or query the database.

Apart from upgrading to 2016, is there anything anyone can suggest that I may be missing?

Comment: Same bitness (x86/x64) for both (Excel/Access)?

Comment: Sorry, not a network guru, but doesn't AV & FW = Audio/Visual and Firewall?  Perhaps a FW is relevant, but they also need to ensure both file and folder rights.  There should be read AND write access both on the file and folder level.  (I guess that is technically not "network", rather file server configuration.  I'm use to the "network guys" dealing with the whole network including servers.)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher yep, same bitness (x86).

Comment: @CPerkins sorry, AV = anti-virus (this has sometimes caused issues over networks), and FW = Firewall, and they've got read/write access to the folders and files in question.

I'm leaning towards a poor/incomplete Excel installation, given that MS Query fails.

I just can't think of what else it might be.

Comment: So what other tests have you attempted?  Can you open the database over the network with Access itself?  Perhaps its possible for something to get screwed up in installation, but I highly doubt that the functionality would work on a local file without everything being properly installed.  Access is just a file-based database.  There is likely no missing or corrupt component that will happen to fix this for a file on a network file server.  All of the functionality should reside in the OS, no special Excel MS Query component for "network" file access.

Comment: When you say "never had a problem like this before", does that mean that you've successfully implemented exactly the same scenario from Excel, importing from Access from a network file server?

Comment: Any error msgs (maybe hidden in eventlog-> apps and services -> microsoft office)? Local version has a copy of the network access file (same file, different location)? ODBC driver version (same for 2010/2016)?

Comment: Access ODBC connections do not like mapped drives. Make sure you use UNC paths.

Comment: @CPerkins yes, I've had several successful implementations of exactly this setup, and the Access database can be opened with Access.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher, I haven't checked Event Logs, and that could possibly be a good place to look. I'll check it out and report back.

Comment: @SunKnight0, I think you may have just opened my eyes to what I've missed! Upon checking, I can confirm that previous successful projects have all used UNC paths! I didn't think that the mapped address would make any difference, but that could be what's causing the issue!

I'll definitely check and get back to you!

Comment: @SunKnight0, I have to wait till tomorrow to test your theory, but just remembered that we did try putting the Access database on the user's desktop, and it still wouldn't connect from the same directory.

Comment: @SunKnight0 no luck, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost too embarrassed to admit, but it turned out to be an incompatibility between Excel 2010 and Access 2016.

Access 2016 installs Access 16.0 Object library, and Excel 2010 then doesn't know what to do with it.

Replacing 2016 runtime with 2010 runtime fixed the problem, and now everyone's happy!